# cannot trigger click event inside of subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have some problem to trigger an click event inside of subscription,
here is the code.

```
replaceResource() {
    // 'replace-file-input' is a file input html element
    const element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('replace-file-input') as HTMLElement;
    // if I put "element.click()" here, eveything works fine.

    // the next line is a subscription of the http request, I want to trigger the click event when I get the response back.
    this.service.checkStatus(this.id).subscribe(
        status => {
            if (status) {
                 // here is the problem, the file input dialog should be opened, but nothing happened
                 element.click()
            }
        }
    )
}
```

Comment: add a console inside the if condition and check whether u ar subscribing to the observable

Comment: file input can only be triggered from user actions, and since subscribe is not inside the scope of direct user actions, your 'programatical' click call has no effect.

Comment: try to ` console.log(status) ` before if (status) and tell us what it is to make sure that the code goes inside the if

Comment: @Sachila Ranawaka I have already tried this, I'm pretty sure element.click() will be executed.

Comment: @Eslam Elhakmey status is true, I'm pretty sure the code goes inside the if statement.

Comment: @ABOS Do you have any suggestions to solve it? I will be very appreciate !

Comment: @MingkaiZheng, as said above, this is a restriction from browser. as a possible workaround, you can enable/disable file input button upfront by checking this.id, i.e. fileInput.disabled = !status;

Comment: @MingkaiZheng , can you try to replace element.click() with document.getElementById('replace-file-input').click() to make sure that it's selecting the wanted element and tell me what happens, maybe it doesn't know what element is. to make sure try to console.log(element) before the event and console.log(element) inside the if and compare both maybe it's calling element from somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ViewChild instead of document.getElementById('id'). ViewChild decorator provides 'nativeElement' object. Maybe this is a problem.

Comment: or you can try something like that - 
`<input type="file" accept="image/*" #file>
<button (click)="file.click()">Upload file</button>`

Comment: I have tried ViewChild, the result is the same, it only works if I put the "element.click()" out of the subscription.

Comment: since I want to open the file input dialog depends on the response of the http request, I cannot just simply use (click)="file.click()" to do it.